# Where to find @c NSError.userInfo dictionary

Tags: ios, firebase, visual-studio, xamarin

I am attempting to integrate Google Firebase's Cloud Firestore database into my application on Xamarin in Visual Studio for Mac. In order to do this I am using the `Plugin.CloudFirestore` and `Plugin.FirebaseAuth` NuGet packages. The issue is whenever I login or create an account using `Plugin.FirebaseAuth` I get the following error:

`An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The @c NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered.`

It seems to be successfully making a call to the Firebase project as the user is created; however, I believe it is having an issue saving the authentication token/information locally. This error only happens on the iOS project. I do not even know where to start with this error because I cannot find the `@c NSError.userInfo dictionary`. If anyone knows where I can find that it would be a huge help.

Also if anyone knows how to fix this error that would be a huge help, but I assume the information in the aforementioned dictionary would be important to fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

In that plugin, `Plugin.FirebaseAuth`, the UserInfo (`NSErrorException` based) is remapped to a plugin defined platform independent `FirebaseAuthException` class.

So look at `Message` property (and then the `Reason` property) of the thrown `FirebaseAuthException` as things are mapped in this exception class based upon the original Firebase error code.

- Example: The `Reason` property contains a localized error message if the Firebase password is determined to be weak:

  ```
  case AuthErrorCode.WeakPassword:
     var reason = userInfo[NSError.LocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] as NSString;
     return new FirebaseAuthException(message, exception, ErrorType.WeakPassword, errorCode, reason);
  case AuthErrorCode.EmailAlreadyInUse:
  ```

re: https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth/blob/b723d9d15d523a24cdfe34dee2353a6f67553756/Plugin.FirebaseAuth/iOS/ExceptionMapper.cs#L1